# Out of directory pick the newest files that have extension that matches predefined requirements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a directory that has many files ...the majority of the files have either extension '.abc' or '.def' and also share the same name...out of these i want to take the newest of each
e.g.

```
fileA.abc  (last writeTime 10:30)  
fileA.def  (last writeTime 10:25)  
fileB.abc  (last writeTime 10:27)  
fileB.def  (last writeTime 10:28)  
fileC.abc  (last writeTime 10:18)  
fileC.def  (last writeTime 10:30)
```

so in the above case it should pick

```
fileA.abc,
fileB.def,
fileC.def
```

I have the below code that of course is not working

```
var fileNames2 = extraDirectory.GetFiles()
    .Where(s => s.Extension == ".abc" || s.Extension == ".def")
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime)
    .GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name))
    .Select(x =>x.First());
```

Comment: How is it obviously not working? What results do you get?

Comment: the out put should be 
fileA.abc,
fileC.def
fileB.def,

Comment: well the code works...i was working on a folder that had files of only one extension...because this folder should be a "mirror" of a folder that definetely carries files with the above specs...same name ,different extension ...i didn't thought that the folder in question was different....thanks for the comments...i did realized it just a few moments just before reading the comments....can i close it somehow ?

Comment: Are you using FileInfo?  It should work.  GetFiles only returns a string and not a Date.